# How to mock up a static method in a static class with URLHelp? (Moq)

Tags: model-view-controller, moq

I have a extension method. Can any one help me how to test this method with Moq?

```
 public static string GetBaseUrl(this UrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        Uri contextUri = new Uri(urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url, urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl);
        UriBuilder realmUri = new UriBuilder(contextUri) { Path = urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath, Query = null, Fragment = null };
        string url = realmUri.Uri.AbsoluteUri;

        if (url.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            url = url.Remove(url.Length - 1, 1); 
        }

        return url;
    }
```

many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TrueWill points out, you can't use Moq directly with UrlHelper.RequestContext because it isn't virtual. On the other hand, UrlHelper is a public class that you can instantiate for use with unit testing.

At some point, however, you will encounter the need to assign a HttpContextBase to create the UrlHelper, and Moq can help you to do that.

Here's a test that shows that I can at least write a unit test that invokes your GetBaseUrl without throwing any exceptions:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    var httpCtxStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    httpCtxStub.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(() =>
        {
            var reqStub = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            reqStub.SetupGet(r => r.RawUrl).Returns("http://foo");
            reqStub.SetupGet(r => r.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://foo"));
            return reqStub.Object;
        });

    var requestCtx = new RequestContext(httpCtxStub.Object, new RouteData());
    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestCtx, new RouteCollection());

    var result = urlHelper.GetBaseUrl();

    // Assert something
}
```

However, this isn't the simplest unit test to write and maintain, so I support TrueWill's comment that you might make life simpler for yourself if you hide UrlHelper behind an interface.

Comment: There's a nice discussion of using interfaces to decouple dependencies using a Gateway pattern of sorts in this podcast: http://www.slickthought.net/post/2009/04/03/New-Spaghetti-Code-Podcast-ndash3b-Donn-Felker-Talks-Mocking.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The UrlHelper.RequestContext property is non-virtual. Moq isn't going to be of help in this case, to the best of my knowledge.

You could create a wrapper class for UrlHelper that implements an interface, but that would seem to defeat the purpose of using an extension method.

[Typemock](http://learn.typemock.com/) would probably do what you want, if you have the budget for a commercial program. (I haven't tried it; I use Moq myself.)

Another option would be to write integration tests against this method; while they would run more slowly than unit tests, I suspect this method is unlikely to version often.

A larger issue is coupling to UrlHelper reducing testability in the rest of your application. Perhaps other posters can suggest answers to that issue.